# Is there a way to know how many pixels a user moves a scrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, pixel

Is there a specific way to know how many pixels a user moves a scrollview? I would dynamically resize a textview accordingly.

Thanks

Fran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html). Specifically check the Responding to Scrolling and Dragging methods, from there you can check the contentOffset property of the scrollview which will give you the x and y offset from the origin.

EDIT: Added the proper name of the contentOffset property.

Comment: Thanks... - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView is good for me, the only problem is when I swipe up (that is I scroll down), 'cause the textview is scrollable and I can't recover the now hidden textfield over the textview, which is contained into the scrollview together with the textview.